# MySQL Syntax error when inserting data (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have the following:

```
def insertion(database, data):
       parsed_data = json.loads(data)
       cursor = database.cursor()
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Food (category, taste) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (parsed_data["category"], parsed_data["taste"]))
       database.commit()
```

However, an error occurs in the in line where I do `cursor.execute(...)`. Specifically:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Sweet)' at line 1`.

Printing out my dictionary reveals no extra parentheses at the end of the `parsed_data["taste"]`. It seems like whatever reason, an extra parentheses is being added which is being interpreted by mySQL has actual SQL syntax? I don't know why this is appearing.

Comment: What is the type/structure of `parsed_data` ?

Answer (score 2):

If the values are strings, you need quotes around them. But the correct solution is to use parameters in `cursor.execute()` rather than string formatting.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Food (category, taste) VALUES (%s, %s)", (parsed_data["category"], parsed_data["taste"]))
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES (%s, %s)" % (parsed_data["category"], parsed_data["taste"])
```

That's your problem. You've got to quote your values. And python's string formatting doesn't do that.

```
VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (parsed_data["category"], parsed_data["taste"])
```

This would probably work better, but even then that's a terrible solution prone to SQL Injection.

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a SQL library for python. We call those "ORM"s

I personally love django's if that can help.